# Change UIView size inside a scroll view

Tags: swift, uiview, scrollview, cgrectmake

I have a View Controller with a UIScrollView inside it.
the scrollView has constraint binding it to to, left, right and bottom of the ViewController. Inside the scrollView I have a nested UIView that I need to constraint to half the height of the View.

I added constraint to bind the uiView to 0 for top, left and right, and I added a height constraint for >= 150 so I could see it in my storyboard.

within the viewDidLoad method I added the following:

```
self.nestedView.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
```

but it has no effect whereas it usually works.
One little thing that may be important: I've set the viewController to "freeform" so I could build up my storyboard.

Is there a way to manage size programmatically ?

Comment: you mentioned adding constraint to bind the view, does that mean you are using auto layout? if so, you are supposed to adjust constraints to change the frame.

Comment: this solution works... thanks